# Bitmap lockbits and cloning

Tags: c#, .net

Can someone familiar with GDI shed some light on why the following sequence throws?

```
var b = new Bitmap("some file");
var bd= b.LockBits(rect , readonly, px); //correct size and pixel type

var clone = (Bitmap)b.Clone();
var cd = clone.LockBits(rect , readonly , px);  //okay

clone.UnlockBits(cd); //okay

b.UnlockBits(bd); //throws -- why?
```

It doesn't throw if I clone before locking the first bitmap, which is the behavior I expected.

I'd also expect that if it lets you clone a locked image, and then allows you to lock/unlock the clone, that the original wouldn't be affected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `Bitmap.Clone()` does not make a deep copy and the data is shared.

Edit: Following the advice given below, move the clone line just after `var b` and make it like this: `var clone = new Bitmap(b);`. It works now.

Comment: Yeah you're right Bitmap.Clone() is a object copy, I think you need to do something like: 
  var clone = new bitmap(b);

Comment: Agreed, it would try to avoid copying the pixels as long as possible.

Comment: @Matt new Bitmap(b) throws when b is locked, though makes more sense in a way.  You can't lock b twice though, so I don't know why it would let me get away with locking a shallow copy.

Comment: @dan, Well move the new Bitmap(b) before locking of the bits. I agree too with you, that cloning Bitmaps is strange.

Comment: Be careful, because the new Bitmap(b) is in fact translated as new Bitmap(Image) and not new Bitmap(Bitmap) and you may be surprised, that only Image properties are transferred, not the bitmap ones(e.g. PixelFormat).