# How do I efficiently crop an *indexed* Bitmap and get an *indexed* result?

Tags: c#, winforms

*If you're here because of the title, you should probably just skip the question and go right to the answers. It turns out I had a simple bug in my code.*

I am trying to work exclusively with indexed images, because a major part of my project involves palette-swapping. I tried the following few lines of code as part of a larger process:

```
        Bitmap raw = ((Bitmap)i).Clone(region, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
        byte transparent = (byte)(Array.FindIndex(raw.Palette.Entries, x => x.A < 128));
        // Scan the bitmap for the first opaque pixel on each side
        BitmapData bd = raw.LockBits(region, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
```

Basically, I wanted to crop the specified `region` of the input, and then do low-level manipulation on that part of the image.

The cast succeeds (and I can verify that it's an indexed bitmap at this point, but it gets stored in a control, hence the loss of type information). The clone call seems to succeed. Debugging shows that the `PixelFormat` of `raw` is indeed `PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed`, and so is that of `(Bitmap)i`. The calculation of the transparent palette index works fine. But then `raw.LockBits` fails, complaining of an invalid parameter.

Even stranger, `raw.LockBits` will succeed if I remove the `.Clone` call (but the rest of the code will do the wrong thing because the source hasn't been cropped).

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646180/bitmap-lockbits-and-cloning), it seems likely that `Clone` with arguments produces some kind of view to the original data, not actually copying it, so that the appropriate data isn't there for `LockBits` to lock - it's not necessarily contiguous. But how do I explicitly copy the region? The usual `Graphics.DrawImage` approach won't work directly, because the desired destination image is indexed so I can't get a Graphics for it.

Do I really have to do all my work in an RGB mode and then convert back? Surely there's **something** more elegant?

Comment: Further, it's distressing to me that a Bitmap might not have its own data buffer, but instead behave like a "view" in that way - if that's actually the problem. I mean, I thought that's part of why the Bitmap/Image distinction exists in the first place...

Comment: Call `LockBits` on the full image and a new one the size of the desired crop, and copy the block you want?  At least the pixels within each line will be contiguous and can be copied together.

Comment: Or just modify your algorithm to support an arbitrary stride that isn't (width in pixels rounded up to four bytes).  Then you can stride through the full image, processing only the portion of interest.

Comment: I was already planning to modify the algorithm along those lines, but it would be nice to have an answer to the question for future reference. Using LockBits and an explicit copy loop sounds brutal, but it would only have to be written once, and should be performant. Worth writing up as an answer I think ;)

Comment: I don't understand why you are cloning the bitmap, if you actually want to just crop the original. I.e. the new bitmap should be a fresh one, created _after_ you know the actual size you need. As for doing the copy, addressing the desired pixel byte for a given x,y pixel location is straight-forward, whether you are addressing the original (i.e. have an x,y offset to deal with) or the cropped copy (i.e. origin 0,0). If you have trouble implementing that, show us what you tried, tell us what happened, and how that was different from what you wanted.

Comment: @Peter Duniho `region` is "the size I need"; there are further low-level manipulations to do other than cropping.

Comment: Well, then I'm having a hard time understand _what_ you're actually trying to do. Assuming `region` is a subset of the original bitmap, then why do you use the same `region` value to clone the original _and_ to lock the copy?

Comment: Hmm, that seems to be a bug. I wanted the width and height from that region (because that's the size of the clone), but not the position... :)

Comment: Looks like I have more bugs. :( Another very surprising behaviour: if the `Rectangle` supplied to `Bitmap.clone` is well out of bounds, e.g. if I replace the X and Y of the `region` with large values, it seems that it throws `System.OutOfMemoryException`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per @Peter Duniho's comment and some further testing and debugging, I determined that in fact I simply had a bug in the code. Conclusion: *The .Clone() method works just fine and is what is desired here*:

```
Bitmap cropped = original.Clone(region, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
```

Or a little more generally,

```
Bitmap cropped = original.Clone(region, original.PixelFormat);
```

Where `region` is the desired cropping `Rectangle`. The problem with my code was that in the subsequent `LockBits` code, that `region` is incorrect - to lock the whole cropped image, I want the same width and height as that `Rectangle`, but (0, 0) for X and Y.

After some more testing, I developed the following notes on errors that can be encountered here:

- If you try to use a `region` that doesn't fit within the `Bitmap`'s rectangle - i.e. `X` or `Y` is negative, or `X + Width` exceeds the `Bitmap`'s `Width`, or `Y + Height` exceeds the `Bitmap`'s Height - it will **not** get clipped to the original `Bitmap`'s bounds, and an exception occurs instead. *Negative width and height values are also not valid*.
- If the `region` for `Bitmap.LockBits` has zero width, zero height, or doesn't fit, it will raise `System.ArgumentException`. The message is just "Parameter is not valid." **either way**, so it's up to you to figure out what went wrong.
- If the `region` for `Bitmap.Clone` has zero width or zero height, you again get `System.ArgumentException`, this time with an actually informative error message. However, if it doesn't fit, *you will instead get a* `System.OutOfMemoryException`. This is somewhat amusing in that width and height values of 0 apparently get checked explicitly, but negative values don't.

So perhaps we should use a little function to guard against that, something like:

```
// Create a cropped `region` of the `original` Bitmap as a new bitmap,
// preserving the original pixel format. If negative Width or Height
// are provided for the clip region and `flipNegative` is set, the result
// is flipped accordingly.
public Bitmap crop(Bitmap original, Rectangle region, bool flipNegative) {
    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), original.Size);
    if (region.Width == 0 || region.Height == 0) { return null; }

    // Normalize width and height parameters,
    // and track whether we might need to flip.
    bool flipHorizontal = region.Width < 0;
    bool flipVertical = region.Height < 0;
    if (flipHorizontal)
    {
        region.X += region.Width;
        region.Width = -region.Width;
    }
    if (flipVertical)
    {
        region.Y += region.Height;
        region.Height = -region.Height;
    }

    // Ensure we have a valid clipping rectangle, and make the GDI call.
    if (!region.IntersectsWith(bounds)) { return null; }
    region.Intersect(bounds);
    Bitmap result = original.Clone(region, original.PixelFormat);

    // Flip the result as appropriate.
    if (flipHorizontal && flipNegative)
    {
        result.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX);
    }
    if (flipVertical && flipNegative)
    {
        result.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY);
    }
    return result;
}
```

(I provided the `flipNegative` argument because you conceivably might want either semantics.)

As for `LockBits`, it's not necessary here, although it's still useful for more low-level manipulations.